# Compilation fail when apply function_traits in a nested lambda

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, lambda

First, I have something like this, a renamed function_traits to get the return type of a lambda

```
template <typename T>
struct FuncAnalyzer
{
};

template <typename T, typename TRet, typename... TArgs>
struct FuncAnalyzer<TRet(T::*)(TArgs...) const>
{
    using TReturn = TRet;
};

template <typename T>
struct FunctionAnalyzer
    : public FuncAnalyzer<decltype(&T::operator())>
{
};
```

then when I have this in a method, that compi:

```
auto a = [](const int& key) -> QString { return QString::number(key); };
using b = FunctionAnalyzer<decltype(a)>::TReturn;
b x;
```

but when I am trying put it in a lambda, it doesn't work

```
    auto c = [](const int& key) -> QString 
    { 
        auto a = [](const int& key) -> QString { return QString::number(key); };
        using b = FunctionAnalyzer<decltype(a)>::TReturn;
        b x;
        return QString::number(key); 
    };
```

Compilation output:

```
1>i:\uicgraph\common\FunctionAnalyzer.h(21): error C2825: 'T': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
1>          Controller\Schema\SchemaController.cpp(105) : see reference to class template instantiation 'ValidSig::FunctionAnalyzer<QString (__cdecl *)(const int &)>' being compiled
1>i:\uicgraph\common\FunctionAnalyzer.h(21): error C2039: '()' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>i:\uicgraph\common\FunctionAnalyzer.h(21): error C2275: 'T' : illegal use of this type as an expression
1>          Controller\Schema\SchemaController.cpp(105) : see declaration of 'T'
1>          Controller\Schema\SchemaController.cpp(105) : see declaration of 'T'
1>i:\uicgraph\common\FunctionAnalyzer.h(21): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '()'
1>i:\uicgraph\common\FunctionAnalyzer.h(21): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'
1>i:\uicgraph\common\FunctionAnalyzer.h(21): error C2947: expecting '>' to terminate template-argument-list, found '>'
1>Controller\Schema\SchemaController.cpp(105): error C2039: 'TReturn' : is not a member of 'ValidSig::FunctionAnalyzer<QString (__cdecl *)(const int &)>'
1>Controller\Schema\SchemaController.cpp(105): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'TReturn'
```

I'm using MSVC 2013

Comment: I tried your code (changed the QString to int, as I don't have Qt installed) and it seems to work in g++ and clang++, see http://rextester.com/JZOU33170 It seems to be a VC problem, as the error appears whenever you change the compiler to VC++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, problem resolved after having rewrote the template

```
template <typename TFunc>
struct FunctionAnalyzer
{
    using ReturnType = typename FunctionAnalyzer<decltype(&TFunc::operator())>::ReturnType;
};

template <typename TClass, typename TRet, typename... TArgs>
struct FunctionAnalyzer<TRet(TClass::*)(TArgs...) const>
{
    using ReturnType = TRet;
};

template <typename TRet, typename... TArgs>
struct FunctionAnalyzer<TRet(*)(TArgs...)>
{
    using ReturnType = TRet;
};
```

It seems be the problem of VS2013. If you take away the third template which is for function pointer, it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

We can reduce the example to

```
template <class T> struct identity {using type = T;};

template <typename T>
struct FunctionAnalyzer
    : identity<decltype(&T::operator())> {};

int main()
{
    []
    {
        auto a = []{};
        using b = FunctionAnalyzer<decltype(a)>::type;
    }();
}
```

This compiles fine [with GCC and Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7dc177d8b453745e).
However, apparently VC++ mistakenly passes `void (__cdecl *)(void)` instead of the actual closure type as the template argument - even though a static assertion such as

```
    static_assert( std::is_class<decltype(a)>::value, "" );
```

*right before* the line inside the lambda [**succeeds**](http://rextester.com/OTA59583). I can really not explain this behavior apart from saying that it's incorrect, as, obviously, a class type isn't a pointer-to-function type. A bug report should be appropriate.

A workaround is to define the lambda outside

```
auto a = []{};
[a] // This is not required by standard! VC++ being stupid I guess
{
    using b = FunctionAnalyzer<decltype(a)>::type;
}();
```

[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/XEIH9685).

Comment: Thank you, I will report this. Any solution to bypass this?

Comment: Further reduced: `int main() { []{ []{}.operator()(); }; }` This is still accepted by gcc and clang, but fails on MSVC with "error C2228: left of '.()' must have class/struct/union"

Comment: @hvd Oh, yeah. I thought the problem was that we tried to access the member from outside the actual context, in a template.